# Is there a place where we can have an exhaustive list of debian's package?

Tags: debian, package-management

Do you know if there is a place where we can have an exhaustive list of debian's package ?

Answer (score 2):

Package lists are stored in the folder

```
/var/lib/apt/lists
```

The `apt-cache` tool can search for packages.

Beside of this you can also search online [Debian Packages](http://packages.debian.org/).